# How to Browse through folders inside the android 2.2 emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I want to know how i can browse through folders using the avd. I know i can use eclipse>DDMS>file explorer to see all the folders and their contents but i want to do this inside the actual emulator. Do i have to install a file manager application? or is there another way? HELP!

Answer (score 0):

File browser may not be coming with emulator, you need to download a file manager apk and install it in your emulator.
You can directly download the apk to your emulator or install using cmd.

```
 adb install [apk file name]
```

*copy the apk file in platform-tools folder of your sdk location*

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the APK](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/) Download it and install in emulator.

- For that you have to copy that `.apk` & paste in `platform-tools` where your `adb` located.
- Open cmd > and go upto your `platform-tools` path.
- Fire > adb install apk file name

Comment: Does it come with those annoying ads?...Anyone reading this, Do not install File Manager.apk

Comment: i don't try that but as you want that apk , i have just find in goolge and i get smiler that. so that is your issue whether you have to install or not.

Comment: thanks.. Let me try that one, i'm currently using file manager and the ads are filling half the screen. again thank you for the link

Comment: @n That apk is working fine without any ads. let me know